# Ionic popup not closing when i select an option

Tags: popup, ionic-framework

The  popup with a list edit is showing when a button clicked.When click on a item in list,an model opens.I need to close the popup when model opens but it doesn't working.

```
$scope.showPopup = function() {
    $scope.data = {}

    $scope.myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        template: '<div class="list padding" ng-click="edit()">Edit</div>',
        cssClass: 'custom-class',
        scope: $scope,
    });
};
$scope.hidePopup = function() {
    $scope.myPopup.close();
}

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});
$scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.hidePopup();
    $scope.modal.show()
}
$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide()
}

$scope.edit = function() {
    console.log(56646);
    $scope.hidePopup();
    $scope.openModal();

};
$scope.update = function(item) {
    $scope.closeModal
    console.log(item);
}
```

please help me?

Comment: Can you give a plunker ?

Comment: please give me the html page?

Comment: i removed that content. i think model inside popup not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $timeout while opening the model.

```
$scope.showPopup = function() {
$scope.data = {}

$scope.myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<div class="list padding" ng-click="edit()">Edit</div>',
    cssClass: 'custom-class',
    scope: $scope,
});
};
$scope.hidePopup = function() {
    $scope.myPopup.close();
}

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});
$scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.hidePopup();
    $scope.modal.show()
}
$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide()
}

$scope.edit = function() {
    console.log(56646);
    $scope.hidePopup();
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.openModal();
    })

};
$scope.update = function(item) {
    $scope.closeModal
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you...for your support